# Will Java Parallel Stream pick next task after current is done?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am trying to use parallelStream in Java for the first time and I have a doubt.
So lets say I have an array of ids- [2, 5, 1, 7, 8]

Now, I have a function f to execute for all these.
lets say time taken for each id is different.
eg - f(2) = 10ms, f(5) = 100ms, f(1) = 90ms and so on.

So, If I use parallelStream like this:

```
ids.parallelStream().map(f)
```

Will it truly be multithreaded? I mean as soon as f(2) finishes, will f(1) be picked up while f(5) is still being executed?

Comment: yes, it's multithreaded check this example https://www.baeldung.com/java-when-to-use-parallel-stream#2-parallel-streams

Comment: Why do you think it would not be "truly multithreaded"? This seems like an odd question. There isn't a guarantee that the actions will be done in parallel, but in practice they will be depending on hardware limitations.

Comment: What is your definition of multi-threaded; versus _truly_ multi-threaded?

Answer (score 2):

The execution will be truly multithreaded if the application is run in a multi-processor environment. The order of execution is not predictable. I have observed that the stream gets partitioned into no more than 32 parts and is executed on as many threads as there are processors (this is a JRE implementation detail that may be different in your environment, I have not run tests on more than 8 processors).

After that, the next thing that affects the order of execution is the way the Spliterator partitions the data. Most obvious way would be to split it into four equal sized parts, but we cannot know that unless we have access to the source code.

Then the way the split streams are assigned to the threads is also implementation dependant.

Then there are almost always other processes or threads running in the environment that might require processor time and delay the execution of any of the split streams.

In parallel computing, if you need to guarantee the order of execution, you need to implement flow control structures like semaphors.